# Want to be able to store user's information into firebase's new angularfire

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have this code below and I am trying to store the user's registration information to be able to store it into firebase's new angularfire. I tried to store the email variable in @ViewChild and I receive the error "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument \"email\" must be a valid string." How should I go about solving this problem?

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';


/**
* Generated class for the RegisterPage page.
*
* See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more        info on
* Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

  @IonicPage()
  @Component({
  selector: 'page-register',
  templateUrl: 'register.html',
  })
  export class RegisterPage {


   //Variables
   fName = " ";
   lName = " ";
   //email = " ";
   //password = " ";
   gender = " ";

   constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
   {}

   ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegisterPage');
   }

   //ViewChild - To get access to a component and its methods, we can use      @ViewChild decorator.
  @ViewChild('email') email = "";
   @ViewChild('password') password = "";

   registerUser() {
    //var email = "myemail@email.com";
    //var password = "mypassword";
    this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
     .catch(function(error) {      
      //Handles Errors here.
       var errorCode = error.code;
       var errorMessage = error.message;
       if(errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        alert('The email is already in use. ');
        } else {
         alert(errorMessage);
     } 

       if(errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
       alert('The email is not valid. ');
       } else {
         alert(errorMessage);
       }

        if(errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        alert('The password is not strong enough. ');
       } else {
         alert(errorMessage);
       }
       console.log(error);

       this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);        
     });
     }
 }
```

Comment: ViewChild() returns an ElementRef. So, to get access of the email's value you should use the follows: this.email.nativeElement.value

Comment: Plus, you are doing a wrong assigment in the email and password. Don't assign them an empty string.